# Multi Thread Server Multiple Port Send File Same Time

Tags: java, multithreading

I use multiple port and Multi thread Server when I send file from client to server like bellow code or from server to client. But I can't send data in same time for different port. I think I must use paralel programing do you have any suggestion for solution or Can you give me source or internet website suggestion for this topic.

Server Side

```
SendFiletoClient(DataSocket1, "test1.txt");
SendFiletoClient(DataSocket2, "test2.txt");
SendFiletoClient(DataSocket3, "test3.txt");
SendFiletoClient(DataSocket4, "test4.txt");
```

Client Side

```
addFileToClient(Socket1, "test1.txt");
addFileToClient(Socket2, "test2.txt");
addFileToClient(Socket3, "test3.txt");
addFileToClient(Socket4, "test4.txt");
```

Comment: "I know I must to use serilazable port", huh? What's "serilazable port"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern for multithread servers is something pseudo coded as:

```
//server side
while (true) {
    accept a connection;
    create a thread to deal with the client;
}
```

Or in a more constructive fashion:

```
while(this.isRunning) {
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    try {
        clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //handle exception on accept client socket
    }
    if(clientSocket != null) {
        Thread workerThread = new Thread(
            new YourWorkerRunnable(clientSocket /*, remain arguments */));
        workerThread.start();  
    } 
}
```

Variations of this pattern include a pool of workerThreads to improve the server-side resource allocation management.

Please refer [to this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) to learn more about coding server sockets.